# Understanding exec > >(command)

Tags: bash

I'm trying to learn the effect of `exec > >(tee logfile)` in the following code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                 

exec 7>&1           # save stdout for later reset                                                                           

exec > >(tee logfile)          # point stdout to FIFO pointing to tee command?                                              
#+expect any subsequent output to stdout to be sent                                                                         
#+both to stdout and logfile.                                                                                               

# so let's send some output                                                                                                 
echo
echo howdy             # expect these strings to be sent both to terminal and                                               
echo g\'day            #+logfile                                                                                            
echo hello!

# restore stdout                                                                                                            
exec 1>&7
exec 7>&-

#check content of logfile!                                                                                                  
echo ------------
cat logfile
```

I'm just guessing here that `exec > >(tee logfile)` will redirect stdout to `>(tee logfile)`.

Here's the output to terminal when this script is run:

```
--------------------

howdy
g'day
hello!

howdy
g'day
hello!
```

And here's the content of logfile:

```
howdy
g'day
hello!
```

It seems my attempt to redirect stdout back to terminal has no effect: `exec 1>&7`. Perhaps, `exec 1>&7` happens AFTER logfile has been written and its content sent to terminal.

And I don't understand the output to terminal when the script is executed. I'm guessing `exec > >(tee logfile)` is blocked until `cat logfile` reads it. Then content of logfile is duplicated to terminal due to `tee logfile`.

Could you help me understand these points?

Thanks.

Comment: It is hard to help you. Because you have not said what you expected to happen.

Comment: Catting logfile at the end of your script adds complexity that does not compensate by an increase in understanding. You already have `echo ---` that, for our purposes, show the same thing: That the stdout is dumped to the terminal.

Answer (score 6):

The general form of the commmand is `exec > output` which causes all further output to stdout to be sent to the file "output".

This can be extended; eg `exec 2> error` will cause all futher output to stderr to be sent to the file "error"

Now, `>(...)` is a bashism that means write the output to a *command*; in this case the command is "tee logfile"

So we add the two together.

`exec > >(tee logfile)` means "write all further output to the command `tee logfile`".

Which means that all future output will be sent to the screen *and* (via `tee`) to the file "logfile"

Comment: `>(command)` does not mean "write the output to a command". It causes **no redirection**. It creates a pipe and connects it to the input of the command, and returns a file-name of the input of the pipe. Therefore `> >(command)` is almost equivalent to `|`. But I don't think that `|` will work here.

Comment: I fail to see how this addresses the asker's concerns. Tee writes to stdout, right? But now stdout is a FIFO to tee. This would generate non-trivial behavior, so I'm must be missing something here because tee does write to the terminal, but I can't find the answer here. By the way, there seems to be some concurrency factor playing here: The prompt is sometimes printed before the whole output of the script has been written to the terminal (can you reproduce it?). If I put a `sleep` or `wait` before `echo` the prompt seems to always show only after the script has been terminated.

Comment: No; stdin is a FIFO to tee 'cos it's `>(...)`.   The more normally seen `<(...)` would make stdout point to the FIFO.

Answer (score -1):

I understand now.

```
$ exec 7>&1
$ exec > >(tee logfile)
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd
fd/     fdinfo/ 
logan@logan-mainPC:~/my-test/learning-process-substitution$ ls -l /proc/self/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 logan logan 64 Feb 14 15:40 0 -> /dev/pts/0
l-wx------ 1 logan logan 64 Feb 14 15:40 1 -> pipe:[9603908]
lrwx------ 1 logan logan 64 Feb 14 15:40 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 logan logan 64 Feb 14 15:40 3 -> /proc/398229/fd
lrwx------ 1 logan logan 64 Feb 14 15:40 7 -> /dev/pts/0
$ echo hi i will restore stdout now
hi i will restore stdout now
$ exec 1>&7
$ exec 7>&-
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 logan logan 64 Feb 14 15:41 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 logan logan 64 Feb 14 15:41 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 logan logan 64 Feb 14 15:41 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 logan logan 64 Feb 14 15:41 3 -> /proc/398237/fd
$ cat logfile 
total 0
lrwx------ 1 logan logan 64 Feb 14 15:40 0 -> /dev/pts/0
l-wx------ 1 logan logan 64 Feb 14 15:40 1 -> pipe:[9603908]
lrwx------ 1 logan logan 64 Feb 14 15:40 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 logan logan 64 Feb 14 15:40 3 -> /proc/398229/fd
lrwx------ 1 logan logan 64 Feb 14 15:40 7 -> /dev/pts/0
hi i will restore stdout now
```

Comment: I don't see that this is an answer. It only demonstrates that the computer knows what to do.